# How to prevent tomcat terminating itself if startup time is >300s

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a grails application running on tomcat that takes a ridiculously long time to start up. It runs in a VM, and the machine is shared by several other VMs. The application runs fast enough when it eventually starts, however it sometimes takes longer than 300 seconds to start up if there are lots of database migrations to run, for example.

If tomcat kills itself after 300 seconds, in the middle of a database migration, then obviously this isn't great.

Is it possible to extend the max startup time to >300 seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845219/tomcat-timeout-eclipse).

Comment: I'm running tomcat standalone, not in eclipse. Using grails run-war. Cheers.

Comment: Possibly `grails.tomcat.startupTimeoutSecs = 500` in your build config?

Comment: Looks like that did the trick, thanks. Go ahead and create an answer here & I'll accept if you're bothered about the reputation points ;-)