# Does Tomcat time its own startup and then self-destruct?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a problem with my web project so I ran Tomcat in debug (FYI, the problem is related to `ClassName.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion() == null`).

When I left the debug paused for too long it would say that Tomcat had encountered a problem and then stopped running.

If I wait twenty seconds and then resume, everything works as normal (In my case my program break but that's a different subject altogether).

Has anyone got any idea why this happens?  There's someone out there who, more than anyone else, I expect to be able to answer this.  His name maybe inferred from the following ingenious riddle: BalusB++ .  I was wondering whether it was a sort of rudimentary health-check that Tomcat performs on itself.

Just kinda curious about this but for the mean time I've got bigger JS-Fish to JS-Fry.

Thanks

Comment: Its related to tomcat startup timeout. Refer for tomcat in eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845219/change-tomcat-servers-timeout-in-eclipse

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the answer actually thanks